# POM failure application resources

Tags: java, maven, web

Even with an `src/main/resources` and the requisite `ApplicationResource.properties`, `ApplicationResource_default.properties` and the "en_US" designation, the pom second below is unable to find the first used message key.  The error is below.  Can someone clarify?

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key "label.common.title" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_US
```

This is the `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>WebApplication3_WIP_maven</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>WebApplication3_WIP_maven</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ostermiller</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.07.00</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apach e.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I don't believe it's a POM related error. I think it's more likely related to your server and web app deployment config.

Comment: @Maaaatt
Thank you, but it is deploying to GlassFish4.1.1. with netbeans Build 201705191307.  Is there any baseline "do first" before deploying a pom app to GlassFish;I would think not, but obviously something?

Comment: Just the type of exception you received gives a lot of information (javax.servlet.jsp). Most likely you have a mistake in your server deployment descriptor (not your pom) which prevents the good deployment of your jsp. What does your web.xml file look like?

Comment: @Maaaatt
It is very simple but is under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.  I could also not understand the error as a breakpoint shows it is compiling up to the last moment

Comment: @Maaaatt
I fixed it partly by changing the <message-resources/> to /ApplicationResource.  However where do I put js files and other content that I want available off WEB-INF.  I have two implementations non-Maven and Maven the non-Maven works and deploys all content, Maven (next layer of the onion) does not.  Ideas?  tia.